# Clustering Words into given Categories in R?

Tags: r, match, cluster-computing, k-means

I have a vector of words and two predefined categories: `cat1 = c("Money, Commercial, Facility")` and `cat2 = c("Debt, Liability, Loans")`. I'm interested in clustering the words in the vector into these two specified categories. While I understand how the kmeans() function works, I'm looking for guidance on how to approach this specific task. Do you have any insights or ideas to get me started on this?

```
`cat1 = c("Money, Commercial, Facility")` 
`cat2 = c("Debt, Liability, Loans")`
words <- c(
  "Rest of the World  Net U S  Exports  Transactions",
  "Net exports of goods and services",
  "All Domestic Sectors  U S  Financial Claims on the Rest of the World  Asset  Level",
  "Labor Force Participation Rate   Men",
  "Other Financial Intermediaries Except Insurance Companies and Pension Funds  Net Lending     or Borrowing      Financial Account   Level",
  "Labor Force Participation Rate   20 Yrs    over  Men",
  "Noncyclical Rate of Unemployment",
  "Farm Business  Included in Nonfinancial Corporate and Noncorporate Business Sectors   Net Lending     or Borrowing      Financial Account   Level",
  "Other Financial Corporations and Insurance Companies and Pension Funds  Net Domestic Claims  Asset  FWTW   Level",
  "Employment Level   Nonagriculture  Unpaid Family Workers"
)
```

Comment: There are fields of study to determine the "sentiment" of a sentence, including natural-language processing (perhaps the [tag:nlp] tag); this is not my field of expertise. You don't have a programming problem here, you have no code to start with, so I think this question should either be migrated to [stats.se] or closed as "needs focus". I hope my mention of NLP gives you a good start for conducting your own research (other than this question).